# Evil Mode, how to rebind the caps-lock key to go into normal mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil

In addition to the Escape key, I would like to go into Normal mode while editing by pressing the `caps-lock` key. How do I achieve that?

Thus far I have been able to *disable* the Caps-lock key using 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-deactivate-caps-lock/

specifically with the command `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps` as mentioned on that website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs does not allow treating the capslock key specially. Generally, treating modifiers specially is something supported differently well, depending on the frontend in use (the X one supports the standard modifiers, so does the Cocoa one).

What you could do instead is remapping the capslock key to a different key Emacs recognizes (such as F13), then bind that key to your desired action in Emacs.